# Parsing Json data into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I'm working on a mobile application using Framework7 & Cordova. I would like to be able to share the content of JSON data into the share function. I am using the Cordova plugin SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.

Here is the link to my JSON data http://www.crewits.net/streaminfo.json

and here is the share function

```
function shareNowPlaying() {

var options = {
  message: 'MESSAGE FROM JSON DATA', 
  subject: 'SUBJECT FROM JSON DATA', 
  files: ['IMAGE FROM JSON DATA'],
  url: 'URL FROM JSON DATA',
  chooserTitle: 'Pick an app' 
}

var onSuccess = function(result) {
  console.log("Share completed? " + result.completed); 
  console.log("Shared to app: " + result.app);  (result.completed=false)
}

var onError = function(msg) {
  console.log("Sharing failed with message: " + msg);
}

window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options, onSuccess, onError);

}
```

Comment: It''s not clear what you want to do. In onSuccess you have access to the result. Just do `console.log(result);` to check out what's available.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just a parse valid JSON in javascript? So:

```
   JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do but in the result, it just shows me this " + data[0].message + "

Answer (score 0):

The link shows a JSON file, if I am not wrong you want to get data from the file and pass it to the function.

Use Jquery:

```
function shareNowPlaying (fileName) {
.
.
.
.
.
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON(fileName, function(jsonData) {
// $.each to get data from jsonData based on your requirement.
});
});
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: thanks @kratos I'm having a problem accessing the data from the options value. In return the message i get back is Now playing " + data[0].message + " on XLR Radio

`var options = {
  message: 'Now listening to " + data[0].message + " on XLR Radio', 
  subject: 'SUBJECT FROM JSON DATA', 
  files: ['IMAGE FROM JSON DATA'],
  url: 'URL FROM JSON DATA',
  chooserTitle: 'Pick an app' 
}`